# What could be causing this USB drive to auto-mount?

Tags: mount

I'm trying to create a USB boot disk. Everytime said disk fails (the system keeps freezing), my first instinct is to run dosfsck to make sure the filesystem wasn't damaged by the crash.

However, Ubuntu (16.04, x64) keeps auto-mounting the device, which makes me worry about screwing it up even more. If I manually unmount the device, Ubuntu just remounts it. I've tried changing the settings in both Cinnamon and Nemo (I don't use Gnome or Unity, BTW), but that didn't help at all.

In my desperation, I booted in recovery mode, thinking that whatever program is auto-mounting won't run, and **THE SAME FREAKING THING HAPPENED IN RECOVERY MODE!!!**

The only real clues I've been able to gather as to what keeps mounting my flash drive are these: the partitions on this drive are mounted in `/media/usb0`, `/media/usb1`, and `/media/usb2`. Also, I briefly noticed one `sh` process that appeared to have the following arguements: `/usr/share/usbmount/usbmount add`.

I have checked my `/etc/udev` folder, and found only 2 rules: one related to snapd, and the other related to VirtualBox. I tried (temporarily) removing both before running `sudo udevadm control --reload`, and it didn't help.

So, what the heck is my computer doing, and how can I make it stop?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I've finally solved my problem. [This RaspberryPi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41959/automount-various-usb-stick-file-systems-on-jessie-lite) post mentions a file called `/etc/usbmount/usbmount.conf`. If you edit that file, there's a line that reads `ENABLED=1`. Changing the "1" to "0" seems to have solved my problem.